# PagingState for Statement in CQL

Tags: java, cassandra, datastax, cql, nosql

I was trying to understand how [PagingState](http://datastax.github.io/java-driver/features/paging/) works with Statement in Cassandra. I tried with a sample that inserts few 1000s of records into database and tried reading the same from DB with fetch size set to 10 and using paging state. This is working perfectly fine. Here is my sample junit code:

```
@Before
public void setup() {
    cassandraTemplate.executeQuery("create table if not exists pagesample(a int, b int, c int, primary key(a,b))");
    String insertQuery = "insert into pagesample(a,b,c) values(?,?,?)";
    PreparedStatement insertStmt = cassandraTemplate.getConnection().prepareStatement(insertQuery);
    for(int i=0; i < 5; i++){
        for(int j=100; j<1000; j++){
            cassandraTemplate.executeQuery(insertStmt, new Object[]{i, j, RandomUtils.nextInt()});
        }
    }
}

@Test
public void testPagination() {
    String selectQuery = "select * from pagesample where a=?";
    String pagingStateStr = null;
    for(int run=0; run<90; run++){
        ResultSet resultSet = selectRows(selectQuery, 10, pagingStateStr, 1);
        int fetchedCount = resultSet.getAvailableWithoutFetching();
        System.out.println(run+". Fetched size: "+fetchedCount);
        for(Row row : resultSet){
            System.out.print(row.getInt("b")+", ");
            if(--fetchedCount == 0){
                break;
            }
        }
        System.out.println();

        PagingState pagingState = resultSet.getExecutionInfo().getPagingState();
        pagingStateStr =  pagingState.toString();
    }
}

public ResultSet selectRows(String cql, int fetchSize, String pagingState, Object... bindings){
    SimpleStatement simpleStatement = new SimpleStatement(cql, bindings);
    statement.setFetchSize(fetchSize);
    if(StringUtils.isNotEmpty(pagingState)){
        statement.setPagingState(PagingState.fromString(pagingState));
    }
    return getSession().execute(simpleStatement);
}
```

When I execute this program, I see that every iteration in testPagination is exactly printing 10 records. But here is what the documentation says:

- **Note that setting a fetch size doesn’t mean that Cassandra will
  always return the exact number of rows, it is possible that it
  returns slightly more or less results.**

I am not really able to understand why Cassandra will return not exactly the same number of rows as specified in fetch size. Is this the case when there is no where clause provided in the query? Will it return exact number of records when a query is constrained on a partition key? Please clarify.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [CQL protocol specification](https://github.com/apache/cassandra/blob/trunk/doc/native_protocol_v3.spec):

> Clients should also not assert that no result will have more than `result_page_size` results. While the current implementation always respect the exact value of `result_page_size`, **we reserve ourselves the right to return slightly smaller or bigger pages in the future for performance reasons**

So it's good practice to always rely on `getAvailableWithoutFetching` instead of the page size, in case Cassandra changes its implementation in the future.

Comment: Sorry for asking for clarification after a  long time. As per the answer things could change in future, but I would like to get an understanding of whether this answer is applicable to both cases i.e. a) query with where clause constrained on a partition key  and 2) for a query without any where clause?

Comment: Yes, it's applicable for any query, regardless of the where clause.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. But I am not able to get it exactly. If the data is spread across multiple nodes, then it can be possible that Cassandra can give slightly less/more number of rows. But when my query is based on a partition key clause, as all the data goes into a specific node, why can not Cassandra give the exact number of results? Can you please help me understand?